# More general version of "finger on the pulse"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

From my understanding when someone is "keeping a finger on the pulse of *x*" that person is keeping a close watch on and has a detailed understanding of the subject or situation.

What would be an expression for someone who monitors a situation to some extent, but doesn't pay attention to anything except major events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Keeping an eye on *x*" would fit the bill in my locality.

Comment: Yes, and to make the extent greater, say "a sharp eye" or "an eagle eye" on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that they are '*keeping tabs on it*'

from TFD

> keep tabs on somebody/something - to watch a person or a situation carefully so that you always know what they are doing or what is happening

Maybe it is too suggestive of close scrutiny, however.